# Warning: "The browser is already running" during the execution of Test Complete test in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, testcomplete

OS: Windows 7
Browser: Internet Explorer 11

I am using TestComplete 10 (by SMARTBEAR). I have recorded a KeywordTest for a website by using IE successfully. I also ran the test 1st time successfully in IE 11 and it passed. When I try to execute the test next time (2nd time), the following warning message was displayed in Test Log and the test execution was stopped:

"The browser is already running"

The following is the command to close the browser (IE) at the last line of my test:

```
BrowserWindow   Close   ... Closes the 'BrowserWindow' window.
```

Comment: I opened "Windows Task Manager" -> then click on Processes tab and I saw iexplore.exe was running. I ended the iexplore.exe process from Windows Task Manager. After that, I ran the test and the test passed successfully.

Comment: I purged the [tag:smartbear-testcomplete] tag from all 6 questions it was in. I saw you adding this tag to questions - **please do not make such a tag when [tag:testcomplete] exists already**. Tag wiki excerpt for it mentions SmartBear already. If you strongly feel that an alternative spelling for that tag is required, propose a synonym.

Comment: Is there any way to kill a process by TestComplete? I like to kill the ie process from Task Manager by TestComplete so that my problem might be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Add the killprocess of iexplore process before the testcase starts

Use sys.process.Find().Terminate();
 = "iexplore"

Killprocess is placed before your IE Launch

Answer (score 0):

```
function terminateIEProcesses() {
var process, i;

for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

    process = Sys.WaitProcess("iexplore", 5000);

    if (!process.Exists) {
        break;
    }
    process.Terminate();
    aqUtils.Delay(5000);
}
}
```